# Sorting Images in Ubuntu Directories by Tag/Keyword

Tags: desktop-background, shotwell

I've looked up various jpg metadata editing tools like exiftool but none of what I found is a solution to what I want to do. I have a single directory of 2000+ wallpapers that in Windows file explorer I can sort by Tag/Keyword and filter visibility by any combination of Tag/Keywords I want. I'm looking for a similar way to do this with Ubuntu. The file manager in Ubuntu doesn't seems to have 'Tags' as a column to sort by.

In Shotwell I can veiw by specific Tags but it wont let be choose any combination of tags to view by. Library doesn't have a sort function by tags in the view port either, so Shotwell isn't very useful.

My plan is to have this huge master archive in one directory and use tag filtering to pick a theme of wallpapers I want to duplicate to another folder to use as a desktop background slideshow. This method works in Windows and I'm trying o figure out a similar way to do it in Ubuntu that makes sense.